# Scroll View inside view not working react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here I am trying a simple code but the scroll view is not working if kept inside another view. Code is like this:

```
  return(
  <View>
    <Toolbar title={this.props.title}>
    </Toolbar>

    <ScrollView>

      <HomeScreenTop />
      <HomeScreenBottom navigator={navigator}/>

      </ScrollView>

  </View>
 );
```

But if scroll view kept as parent view it works perfectly. Code is as below:

```
  return(
  <ScrollView>
    <Toolbar title={this.props.title}>
    </Toolbar>

      <HomeScreenTop />
      <HomeScreenBottom navigator={navigator}/>

  </ScrollView>
 );
```

Now the problem is I don't want my toolbar to scroll up and down, I just want the contents below the toolbar to move. How can I achieve that?

And next question: Is scroll view has to be parent view to be returned to work?

Comment: Don't forget the minHeight

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312631/react-native-scrollview-not-scrolling-on-android This will help you a lot.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the property flexGrow in the style, flex didnt worked for me.

```
 <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    ...
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am rendering child component which has scrollview and also parent has scrollview. I am not able to properly handle this. Can you help me out?

Comment: Does nothing in my case.

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Comment: Remove `flex: 1` from 'contentContainerStyle` it breaks the scrolling. And add `flexGrow: 1`.

Answer (score 48):

you should wrap toolbar in view like this:

```
<View><Toolbar/></View>
```

Wrap those component which you want to scroll inside scrollview as:

```
<ScrollView>your expected components...</ScrollView>
```

And provide flex to root view as:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
```

Finally your code will run as you expected.

Comment: not having flex:1 on the root view was causing a similar problem for me. Added flex:1 to the root view and bam! Scrolling works.

Answer (score 14):

Top `<View>` must has style `flex:1`, and also `<ScrollView>` has too

Comment: After adding this I am unable to scroll on both IOS and Android.

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 13):

This was driving me crazy because I added `<view> and <ScrollView>` like everyone suggested but nothing worked. Then I closed the terminal then rebuild the application again using:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Then, it started working. I hope this saves someone's sanity :)

**FYI, just hitting r (or refreshing) was not working either. I had to rebuild it.**

Answer (score 4):

For me, Scroll View wrapped with TouchableWithoutFeedback was causing scroll view to not function at times.

Answer (score 3):

I set height property for  style . then it's work for me .

My code :

```
 <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
       <ScrollView >
         <XYZ/>
       </ScrollView>
 </View>
```

Styles :

```
 listWrapper:{
    // flex:1,
    // flexGrow:1,
    width:'80%',
    height:300,
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont use contentContainerStyle on Scroll View Just use simple style prop for styling of scroll View . You will not face any problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

None of these solution worked for me, after very long I found that height of a View inside the code is causing the problem so instead of

`height:'50%'`
I change it to
`height:300`
and it worked, as show below:

```html
 <ScrollView>
...
   <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height: 100,
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
      height:300,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      padding: 20,
      margin: 5,
    }}>

...
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<Form>` from native base and you want to scroll
then use KeyboardAwareScrollView

```
<KeyboardAwaareScrollView enableOnAndroid={true}>
.
.

</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

this will work on Android

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way:

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

          <View
            style={{
              overflow: "hidden",
              flex: 1,
              borderTopStartRadius: 40,
              borderTopEndRadius: 40,
              flexGrow: windowHeight,
            }}
          >
            <ScrollView
              contentContainerStyle={{
                flexGrow: windowHeight,
                backgroundColor: Colors.primary_color,
                padding: 10,
              }}
            >
</View>

...
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view didn't work for me as expected because there weren't enough items to scroll through. I expected the scroll view on Android to behave similarly to iOS, where the scrolling effect is still noticeable even with a minimal number of items. Once I added more items to the scroll view, the scrolling effect became visible on both devices.

- Adding more items to the Scrollview work for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

The `<View>` enwrapping your `scrollView` container should have a styling with `flex:1`

```html
<View style={styles.container}>
    {/* Container */}
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}>
```

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    scrollViewContent: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        // flex: 1,
        paddingVertical: 16,
    },
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting an answer, try to look through existing answers so that you don't post a duplicate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Update 2020-02: It will work with React.Fragment `<>` and `</>` or `<React.Fragment>` and `</React.Fragment>`. So Try this.

```
return(
  <>
    <Toolbar title={this.props.title}>
    </Toolbar>

    <ScrollView>

      <HomeScreenTop />
      <HomeScreenBottom navigator={navigator}/>

    </ScrollView>

  </>
 );
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score -1):

Use react fragments instead of a **View** to wrap your scroll view it worked for me

```
<>
<ScrollView>
 .......... 
</ScrollView>
</>
```

Answer (score -3):

if you are using `position: "absolute",` delete it and try. 
You can try

```
<SafeAreaView>

<ScrollView>

</ScrollView>

</SafeAreaView>
```