# Vertical ScrollView Not Working In Android React Native 57.8

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, scrollview

I have this simple code :

```
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <ScrollView >
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                <Text>TEST</Text>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
```

ScrollView does not work at all when being in vertical mode but when switch to horizontal it's work, in IOS work for both,
I search many times for solutions but not solved

Comment: In Android `ScrollView` is scrollable if and only if content is too long to be displayed. Is this your case in vertical mode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137388/scroll-view-inside-view-not-working-react-native

Comment: @Milore very thanks i try long list and it's work (:

Comment: Try adding more `<Text> Test <Text>`. You will get clarity.

Comment: Yes @Ron  i added more <Text> and scroll view work