# react native scrollview not scrolling on android

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following component:

```
export default class StoreComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scroll}>
          <StoreCarouselComponent />
          <StoreDiscountComponent />
          <StoreDetailsComponent />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

with this style

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  scroll: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: 350,
  },
  box: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 30,
    position: 'absolute',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.34,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 10
    },
    elevation: 10,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 410,

  },
  boxDiscount: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 30,
    position: 'absolute',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.34,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 10
    },
    elevation: 10,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
    backgroundColor: '#253241',
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 320,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30
  },
  distance: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#767676'
  },
  distanceElement: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#44D9E6'
  },
  address: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#767676'
  },
  category: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#767676',
  },
  categoryElement: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#44D9E6',
  },
  hr: {
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  icons: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});

export default styles;
```

my scrollview works on ios but on android don't and I don't understand why

here a an image of the app and as you can see I need to scroll on android:

[image]

Answer (score 19):

try to import from

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

instead of from

> 'react native'

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life! Not sure why it wasn't included in react-native itself. I'm going to check what react-native-gesture-handler does.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, but it'd nice to know why we have to use this as opposed to the one from React Native. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @ZeivRine can you explain why this works?

Answer (score 15):

Use `flexGrow : 1` inside your styles.scroll instead of `flex:1`

Comment: if it's oki to you to change the schema (swap the ScrollView with the view). use this : 
```
export default class StoreComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scroll}>
     <View style={styles.container}>        
          <StoreCarouselComponent />
          <StoreDiscountComponent />
          <StoreDetailsComponent />
      </View>
</ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```
if this doesn't work , can you please add nestedScrollEnabled={true} props to your Scrollview ?

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. The culprit turned out to be `contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}` on my ScrollView. Removing that (It turned out to be unnecessary, anyway.) fixed the problem on Android.

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 4):

use `flex: 1` inside `style={styles.container}` and delete it from `.scroll`

Comment: Thank u. Solved my issue

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 2):

the styles on your scroll contentContainerStyle is uneccessary

try to remove : styles.scroll

and just give padding or margin on component  if you to center it

if its row add props horizontal = true on ScrollView.

Comment: thanks, but without the style my content is aling to the left, also a need to scroll vertically no horizontally.

Comment: if you dont want to modify your child components margin/padding . another options is  add this to your ScrollView  contentContainerStyle={{width:'100%', alignItems:'center'}}

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar structure as mentioned in question. I had 3 direct children `View` inside `ScrollView` and it wasn't scrolling. I tried all above solutions with flex, flexGrow etc. Nothing worked for me.

What worked for me is wrapping all 3 direct children to another `View`, so for `ScrollView` there's only one direct children.

```
// THIS DOES NOT SCROLL
<ScrollView>
  <View>// 1st direct children</View>
  <View>// 2nd direct children</View>
  <View>// 3rd direct children</View>
</ScrollView>


// THIS WILL SCROLL, As now ScrollView has only one direct children
<ScrollView>
  <View>
    <View>// 1st children</View>
    <View>// 2nd children</View>
    <View>// 3rd children</View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```